# From Site.com, the Account (Standard Object) shows no data in Data Repeater

Tags: account, site.com

I can't seem to get Site.com to see any data from the Account object when I set up a Data Repeater. I've set and reset the Guest User Profile permissions on the Account many times, and still nothing. There is a ton of data and Account records that should be visible there.

I can get the Campaign (Standard Object) to connect just fine via a Data Repeater, and I see the data there. But no luck on the Account object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that this is being caused by the sharing model in your org.  If the org-wide default for Accounts is private, you have to make sure that there is some way the Account records that you need to display are being shared with the Site's Guest User.  You may have to [create an Account sharing rule](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_rules_create_account.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the issue. Many thanks Peter!